Contract annotation for not throwing a NPE
I have this method to reduce boilerplate doing null checks
@Contract("_ -> !fail")
@Nullable
public static <T> T valueElseNull(@NotNull final Supplier<T> supplier) {
  try {
    return supplier.get();
  } catch (final NullPointerException npe) {
    return null;
  }
}

so instead of writing:
object.setField(source.getFoo() != null ? source.getFoo().getBar() : null);

I can simply write:
object.setField(valueElseNull(() -> source.getFoo().getBar()));

But IntelliJ still warns me about that source.getFoo().getBar() might throw a NPE, while I know this method will handle that.
I've tried fixing that warning with a @Contract annotation as shown above, but there is no such construct as !fail unfortunately.
How can I fix this warning?
Or does such an utility method already exist (in Apache Commons for example)?
Or should I not do this, and why not?
Thanks in advance!

The contract would need to be that of the supplier, not your method's. Nevertheless, you shouldn't do it. It's confusing/surprising. Handling exceptions is quite expensive. It hides problems. Why not something like NullUtils.map(source.getFoo(), foo -> foo.getBar())?

Catching NPEs is usually frowned upon, for several reasons:

It's confusing/surprising
Throwing and catching exceptions is comparatively expensive
It might mask other problems
It's not clear where the exception is thrown (by your method call or somewhere deep down the call stack)

And regardless of above points, you would need the annotation on the Supplier, not your method. The exception is thrown in the supplier and only caught in your method.
I would propose a different approach instead:
@Nullable
public static <T, R> R withNullable(
    final T value,
    final Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
  final T value = supplier.get();
  return value != null
      ? mapper.apply(value)
      : null;
}

And then use:
object.setField(withNullable(source.getFoo(), foo -> foo.getBar()));
object.setField(withNullable(source.getFoo(), Foo::getBar));


This looks pretty elegant actually, thank you!

You can streamline this further without sacrificing clarity by using the map function in Java 8's Optional:
Optional.ofNullable(source.getFoo()).map(Foo::getBar).orElse(null);

This way, you're directly accessing the value property of Foo, or returning null otherwise.

You can add a map after the ofNullable call to get the value (getBar)

I did edit the answer to match this

Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a reusable method. Also, I understood that the usage of Optional is discouraged because of the performance overhead by creating an Optional object.
